# Receiving 7 digits instead of 6 digits - Firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase mobile authentication for more than 3 years and I have never faced issue. All of a sudden, the users, especially in Australia, are receiving 7 digit OTP instead of usual of 6 digit OTP.

Another issue is when user receive the 7 digit OTP, they don't get the text as well that they usually get. (459665 is your verification code for *****). Just the 7 digit OTP.

Is anyone else facing this issue? I looked into the Firebase library, but i couldn't find a provision to fix the no. of digits to 6.

Kindly assist me with this issue.

P.S.: As of now, only Android users have reported this. Not sure about iOS yet